# Block scope in ES5

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-5, iife

I am having a problem with an assignment. This is the assignment:

> Given following function.

```
let rechne = function(x,y,operation) {
  let ergebnis = x - y;
  if (!operation) {
    let ergebnis = x + y;
    console.log(ergebnis);
  }
  return ergebnis;
}
```

> Rewrite the function so that the desired block scope of the variables
>   can be achieved in ES5.

So I wrote this:

```
 let rechneScope = function(x,y,operation) {
   (function(){
     let ergebnis = x - y;
   })()

   if (!operation) {
     (function(){
       let ergebnis = x + y;
       console.log(ergebnis);
     })()
   }

   return ergebnis;
}
```

Presumed I called that function in a console.log like `console.log(rechneScope(10, 2))`
I would expect the first variable to be 8 and the second one to be 12.

But when I reload the browser, the console always prints 12 for the second variable and for the first variable the result differs. Sometimes 2, sometimes 8, sometimes 15. I am really confused. Why is this happening?

Comment: If you are using IE11 and above then you don't need to worry. `let` and `const` work in IE11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're assumption that the desired output is `8` then `12` is wrong. The first `console.log` that gets executed is the one with `ergebnis = x + y`, so you should see `12` then `8`.

Next, `let` was introduced in ES6 so if you're limiting yourself to ES5, you're only allowed to use `var`.

Finally, make sure your you wrap the entire scope of each variable in an IIFE. You have `return ergebnis` outside of the first function so that variable won't be in scope anymore at the time that line of code executes.

The correct implementation would be something like this:

```js
var rechneScope = function(x, y, operation) {
  return (function() {
    var ergebnis = x - y;
    if (!operation) {
      (function() {
        var ergebnis = x + y;
        console.log(ergebnis);
      })()
    }
    return ergebnis;
  })()
}

console.log(rechneScope(10, 2))
```

I know it's not part of your assignment, but just for reference, [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) doesn't bother with trying to emulate ES6 scope. Here's how the same thing would be compiled by Babel:

```
"use strict";

var rechne = function rechne(x, y, operation) {
  var ergebnis = x - y;

  if (!operation) {
    var _ergebnis = x + y;

    console.log(_ergebnis);
  }

  return ergebnis;
};
```

Comment: +1                                                                                                 for simply using a different variable name to achieve the distinction.

Answer (score 1):

You are making minor mistakes.

1. You are using the let keyword which cares about the scope and
   because of that your 'ergebnis' is undefined in return.
2. You are not printing the output in first block.

Solution is to remove return statement and print the answer in each block. You will get the desired result

```
let rechneScope = function(x,y,operation) {
   (function(){
     let ergebnis = x - y; 
     console.log(ergebnis);
   })()

   if (!operation) {
     (function(){
       let ergebnis = x + y;
       console.log(ergebnis);
     })()
   }
}
rechneScope(10, 2);
```